# jQuery preventDefault and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have the following code which is working in all browsers but not Safari on mobiles and older versions of desktop safari. Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
    var segment = jQuery(location).attr('href').split("/")[3];                      
segment = segment.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter) {
    return letter.toUpperCase();                                                
});
var type = "Download";                                                          

jQuery('a').each(function() {                                                   
    if(
        (jQuery(this).attr('href').substr(-3) == 'pdf') || 
        (jQuery(this).attr('href').substr(-3) == 'doc') || 
        (jQuery(this).attr('href').substr(-3) == 'docx') || 
        (jQuery(this).attr('href').substr(-3) == 'ppt') || 
        (jQuery(this).attr('href').substr(-3) == 'pptx') || 
        (jQuery(this).attr('href').substr(-3) == 'xls') || 
        (jQuery(this).attr('href').substr(-3) == 'xlsx')
    ){                                                                          
        var filename = jQuery(this).attr('href').substr(jQuery(this).attr('href').lastIndexOf('/')+1)       
        var href = jQuery(this).attr("href");                               
        var target = jQuery(this).attr("target");                           
        jQuery(this).click(function(event)
        {                                                       
            event.preventDefault();
            _gaq.push(["_trackEvent", segment, type, filename, , false]);
            setTimeout(function() {                             
                window.open(href,(!target?"_blank":target));
            },200); 
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Seriously inefficient code. Please do not use jQuery where not needed and cache the href in a var by moving `var href = jQuery(this).attr("href");` to before the if! Is this code running after page load or not?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, it's running at the foot of the page.

Comment: `filename, , false` can't help.